# execute php file, then email and log output

Tags: php, cron, command-line-interface, ubuntu-16.04

I've got a cron job I want to execute a PHP file, then take the output and both email and save to a log file.

I can use this to email:

```sh
/path/to/php /path/to/script.php | mail -s "script results" my@email.com
```

And I can use this to save to a log file:

```sh
/path/to/php /path/to/script.php >> /path/to/logfile.log 2>&1
```

But this doesn't work for me as I expected:

```sh
/path/to/php /path/to/script.php | mail -s "script results" my@email.com >> /path/to/logfile.log 2>&1
```

It appears to be emailing the output, but not writing to the log file.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @user3783243 The way the web host has the server set up complicates this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is `tee` command.

You can do it like this

```
/path/to/php /path/to/script.php 2>&1 | tee -a /path/to/logfile.log | mail -s "script results" my@email.com
```

[See more about tee](https://www.howtoforge.com/linux-tee-command/)